# Como usar herramienta Timer y TimerTask

Tags: java, android

Quiero que el programa verifique cada segundo sí se cumple la condición del `if` , pero me salen unos errores ,no se que estoy haciendo mal, este es el código :

```
package alarmexample.example.com.alarmexample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {


public  String getHora(String strFormato) {

    Calendar objCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(strFormato);

    String strHora = simpleDateFormat.format(objCalendar.getTime());
    return strHora;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            startAlert();}

public void startAlert() {

    String hora_sistema = getHora("HH:mm:"); //Obtenida con el método
    String horaTuya = "03:13:";

    int timeInSec = 5;

    if (horaTuya.equals(hora_sistema)) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                this.getApplicationContext(), 234, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (timeInSec * 1000), pendingIntent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "La alarma sonará en " + timeInSec + " segundos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "no hay nada ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
                     }
           },0,1000);//Cada segundo.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) y [TimerTask](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) no son "herramientas", son clases de java que te ayudan a programar una ejecución única o repetida con un temporizador.

El método `startAlert();` lo debes de llamar dentro del `Handler`, no debes llamar la declaración de todo el método dentro de `onCreate` únicamente `startAlert();` :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    public  String getHora(String strFormato) {

        Calendar objCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(strFormato);

        String strHora = simpleDateFormat.format(objCalendar.getTime());
        return strHora;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                startAlert();  //*** Aquí!!!

                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        };

        handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);




    }   

   public void startAlert() {


        String hora_sistema = getHora("HH:mm"); //hora sistema
        String mihora = "23:57"; //hora establecida

        int timeInSec = 5;

        if ( mihora.equals(hora_sistema )){


            Toast.makeText(this, " hola,despierta ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }else {Toast.makeText(this, "aún no es la hora ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias,ya me está funcionando.

Comment: @Alexander Excelente Saludos!

Answer (score 2):

No estaría de mas que indicaras de que errores hablas. 
Aún y así he podido ver lo siguiente:

1:
No puedes actualizar la UI desde dentro de hilo separado del principal.
Prueba con esto:

```
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        private Handler updateUI = new Handler(){
            @Override
            public void dispatchMessage(Message msg) {
                super.dispatchMessage(msg);
                startAlert();
            }
        };

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            updateUI.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
    },0,1000);//Cada segundo.
```

2:
Crea la clase MyBroadcastReceiver que extiende de BroadcastReceiver.